# How to create java class in jni folder? is it possible?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, ndk-build

I want to hide my java code.So i crate java class inside jni folder and trying to call that class method.But I'm getting ClassNotFound exception while find class in c++.is it possible?.This is my first ndk project.so i don't know about this.Please tell me solution.

this is my c++ code

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL 
Java_com_example_sohamsaa_ndktest_MyNativeClass_startRecord(JNIEnv* env,jobject obj){

jclass cls2 = env->FindClass("jni/MyTest");//here i'm getting classnotfound exception  

if(cls2 == NULL) {
   cerr << "ERROR: class not found !";
}
else {                                 
   cout << "Class MyTest found" << endl;
   jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls2, "mymain", "()V"); 
   if(mid == NULL)
       cerr << "ERROR: method void mymain() not found !" << endl;
   else {
       env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls2, mid);                     
       cout << endl;
   }
}
return (*env).NewStringUTF("Hi siddharthan");
}
```

this is my java class

```
public class MyTest {
   public static void mymain() {  
      System.out.println("Hello, World in java from mymain");
  }
}
```

Comment: *I want to hide my java code.* Hide it from who?  The owner of the device you deploy your app on?

Comment: @Andrew Henle thanks for reply .Some client want to implement my code in his project.So i want to give only function name.But if i make jar file they can see my code.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, yes you could put a class in the JNI folder. However, it would not achieve the result that you desire:

1. The Android runtime (the classloader) would not be able to find the class, so you would get a runtime exception when your app attempted to load it.
2. The person who owns the device on which your app has been installed would be able to find the class.  It will be stored in the file system somewhere.

Basically, it won't work.  You cannot hide the code if you want the user's device to be able to run it.